# Cannot connect to docker compose containers on Mac

Tags: docker, macos, docker-compose, docker-desktop

When I run `docker-compose up` and try to connect via the docker address IP shown in inspect or docker desktop, it doesn't connect

after some investigation it seems I should publish or bound the docker port with mac localhost, but I can't the right commend to do with *docker-compose*

[image: container]

[image]

[image: Not bounded]

commend to connect to VM containers of docker compose from mac localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind/expose the inner port (:3000) in the container to the host.

In your docker-compose.yaml file include:

```
ports:
- "3000:3000"
```